# How are signals and KeyboardInterrupt handled in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, signals, interrupt

I have two Python scripts `foo.py` and `bar.py`, `foo.py` will call `bar.py` via `os.system()`.

```
#foo.py
import os

print os.getpid()
os.system("python dir/bar.py")
```

```
#bar.py
import time

time.sleep(10)
print "over"
```

Say the pid of `foo.py` is 123, if the program terminate normally, it'll print

```
123
over
```

If I type `kill 123` while it's running, I'll get the following output

```
123
Terminated
over
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> while it's running, I'll get something like

```
123
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir/bar.py", line 4, in <module>
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

But if I type `kill -SIGINT 123` while it's running, it seems the program will just ignore the signal and exit normally.

```
123
over
```

---

It seems to me that,
if I type `kill 123`, the sub-process will not be affected.
if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, both processes will be terminated.
if I type `kill -SIGINT 123` while the sub-process is running, the signal will be ignored.

Can someone please explain to me how it works?
Isn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and `kill -SIGINT` supposed to be equivalent?
If I type `kill 123` is it guaranteed that the sub-process will not be affected (if it happens to be running)?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider each case in turn:

> if I type `kill 123`, the sub-process will not be affected.

Yes, that's how `kill [pid]` works. It sends a signal only to the process you want to kill.  If you want to send the signal to an group of processes, then you have to use the negative number representing the [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).

> if I type Ctrl-C, both processes will be terminated.

I assume you mean "terminated by Ctrl-C". Actually, that's not the case: only the child is terminated. If you add at the end of `foo.py` a line like this one `print "I'm a little teapot"`, you'll see this line gets printed. What happens is that the child gets the signal. The parent then continues from `os.system`. Without the additional line, it *looks* like the parent was also affected by the Ctrl-C but it is not the case, as the additional line shows.

You shell does send the signal to the process group that is associated with the tty, which *includes* the parent. *However*, `os.system` uses the [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) call which blocks the `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` signals in the process that makes the call. So the parent is immune.

If you do not use `os.system`, *then* your process will be affected by the `SIGINT`. Try this code for `foo.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess

print os.getpid()
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "dir/bar.py"])
p.wait()
print "I'm a little teapot"
```

If you hit Ctrl-C while this runs, you'll get two tracebacks: one from the parent, one from the child:

```
$ python foo.py 
29626
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir/bar.py", line 4, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt    p.wait()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1389, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

> if I type `kill -SIGINT 123` while the sub-process is running, the signal will be ignored.

See above.

> Isn't Ctrl-C and `kill -SIGINT` supposed to be equivalent?

Ctrl-C does send a `SIGINT` to foreground process group associated with the tty in which you issue the Ctrl-C.

> If I type `kill 123` is it guaranteed that the sub-process will not be affected (if it happens to be running)?

By itself `kill 123` will send the signal only to the process with `pid` 123. Children won't be affected.